# android studio java firebase firestore concurrent data update

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, concurrency

I am using the below code to update a firebase firestore database named "Courses".

```
db.collection("Courses").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                    loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                        Courses c = d.toObject(Courses.class);
                        c.setId(d.getId());
                        coursesArrayList.add(c);
                    }
               
                    courseRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                
                    Toast.makeText(CourseDetails.this, "No data found in Database",       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(CourseDetails.this, "Fail to get the data.",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

As far as I know firebase firestore upholds a serializable isolation model. This is what I would like to know. Let's say this single line command starts to get executed at the sime time on two different android devices. Does one of these two commands wait for the other command to finish to get executed?

I did not try this yet since this is a multiuser problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each write operation to Firestore is executed atomically. So you can never end up with a partial write from one client, and a partial write from another client.

But if multiple clients write the same data, the last write will be the one that you end up with in the database. With the [default write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) there is no coordination of those operations across the clients.

If you want to ensure that the write operations between clients are isolated or coordinated, use [batched writes or transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for them.

Comment: There is just one thing I need to know about transactions. If two transactions on the same database are executed concurrently on two different devices does one of the transactions wait for the other one to finish to get executed?

Comment: If you use one of the client-side SDKs, they use a compare-and-set approach. When your transaction reads a document, it tracks what version of that document it read. When you then write the document - and commit the transaction - it sends the version number and the new data to the server. The server checks if the current version is still the same, and only commits the data if it is. If the version has changed, it tells the client to retry.

Comment: The concept is quite different from what most devs are used to, so I recommend reading up on compare-and-set (sometimes also called compare-and-swap) type transactions.

Comment: In firestore's online documentation I have read something like this: In the Mobile/Web SDKs, a transaction keeps track of all the documents you read inside the transaction. The transaction completes its write operations only if none of those documents changed during the transaction's execution. If any document did change, the transaction handler retries the transaction. If the transaction can't get a clean result after a few retries, the transaction fails due to data contention.

Comment: Does this mean this?: If two transactions on the same firebase database are executed concurrently on two different devices one of the transactions essentially waits for the other one to finish to get executed?

Comment: I need to know one more thing. I am using email and password based authentication for my android studio application. If two registration requests with the same email and password come from two devices at the same moment to the authentication server, how does the server choose which request to accept first and reject the other one? Since as far as I know the email and password based authentication can not make two records that have the same email and password.